# How to Send user attributes from Interaction Studio to Cloudpages

Tags: api, cloudpage, parameters, attribute, interaction-studio

I have a popup that appears when a user visits the sites homepage.
This popup asks the user to update their email address by visiting a cloudpage.
The campaign only targets specific users, and campaign and template are built in Interaction Studio.

Given that, the user that is viewing the campaign is already known and will have certain attributes associated with them and have an existing profile in Interaction Studio.

Is is possible to pass some user attributes such as an id, current email address as parameters within a URL to a Cloudpage in Marketing Cloud.

For example the user clicks a button that takes them to the Cloudpage that allows them to input their new email address and the URL would be something along the lines of

https://cloudpages.mysite.com/?userid=USERID&email=OLDEMAILADRESS

Can I create variables that dynamically get populated for USERID and OLDEMAILADDRESS?

Getting the parameters from the URL on the Cloudpage is not a problem, thereafter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This documentation which is helpful on this topic

https://doc.evergage.com/display/EKB/Users+and+Accounts+Export+API

User attributes can be retrieved via an API call